# Similar package as apt-get install socket for centos 6.9

Tags: centos6

I need to run a socket on CentOS as we have `socket` installed on Ubuntu. Is there any similar way I can do it on CentOS?

**NOTE:** I can run simply `socket` on Ubuntu by `socket -sl 555 -B 0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Background

Based on your question, I'm going to assume you mean you have this package, `socket` on your Ubuntu boxes:

```
$ sudo apt-cache show socket
Package: socket
Priority: optional
Section: universe/net
Installed-Size: 76
Maintainer: Ubuntu MOTU Developers <ubuntu-motu@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: LENART Janos <ocsi@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.1-10
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
Filename: pool/universe/s/socket/socket_1.1-10_amd64.deb
Size: 16846
MD5sum: b258cb002cd0bf83ef7cd81ea8ebc203
SHA1: 45964483ba4c7b29ac90ec6ddd57b87bb2c8f507
SHA256: 9b3496c61a5d81241ab83c7541de456a4e0f8d2ade3eaa122e6f64ab28e81c2b
Description-en: Multi purpose socket tool
 The socket program is a simple tool for socket based connections. It
 can be used to create simple daemons (in both standalone and inetd
 mode), to connect to other daemons or to redirect ports.
Description-md5: 286dc3011950982c9923a6a69c875ca9
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

I don't see this package available in any CentOS YUM repository and from the looks of it, it's quite dated. Appears to not have been updated since 2009:

> 2009-04-14 - LENART Janos 
>   socket (1.1-10) unstable; urgency=low
>   * (Re-) Adopting the package. (closes: #487341)
>   * Applied excellent patch from Andras Pal 
>   + Fixed some missing headers
>   + (hopefully) complete support for UNIX domain sockets

- source - [socket_1.1-10_amd64.deb - pkgs.org](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/socket_1.1-10_amd64.deb.html)

#### Alternatives

Given all this I'd be inclined to use `nc` (netcat) or `socat`. There's [several recipes](https://github.com/craSH/socat/blob/master/EXAMPLES) that show how to do things using `socat`.

Something similar to what you're showing with this command:

```
$ socket -sl 555 -B 0.0.0.0
```

Can be achieved with `nc`, for example:

```
$ nc -4 -l -p 555 -k
```

Or with `socat`:

```
$ socat - tcp-l:555,ignoreeof
```

Comment: awesome. If you could explain a bit about ignoreeof

Comment: `ignoreeof`, tells the connection to stay up, even after a client disconnects from it.